# Securely fetching an array that's for a specific user from a database using Auth0

Tags: swift, database, nosql

I think I'm in over my head.

What I wanted to happen was for users to be able to log into my swiftui app, and then the app being able to securely fetch an array of countries they've been to from a database, with them only being able to fetch this array when logged in and being unable to see anyone else's array.

My idea was to use Auth0, similarly to how auth0 already holds the name, email , profile picture etc, to add another field that holds the array of countries.

Apparently though this isn't what you're supposed to do, and you're supposed to use an external database or something. I have no idea how to authenticate access to this external database using auth0 and then access or be able to update this array.

My search led me down to something called Firebase and AWS lambda and I'm supposed to link these together somehow but i'm already beyond lost, surely there's a less convoluted way to do this.

All my googling regarding auth0 and connecting or using it with databases only shows up results on how to use auth0 with an external base used for the purposes of holding log-in information, not how to access the database by an already authenticated user.

In my head i thought it would go something like this:
Login via auth0 -> now you can fetch your user data from this database -> fetch user data, with auth0 somehow providing proof that you are who you are (perhaps using the JWT it spits out)